# Unable to use router.push in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Reactjs and using nextjs,Right now i am trying to refresh page (using routes) but i am getting following error

```
Error: No router instance found. you should only use "next/router" inside the client side of your app.
```

Here is my current code

```
const Post = ({ post, blogs }) => {
    const routers = useRouter();
    var spath=routers.asPath;
    routers.push({ pathname: spath, query: '' });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably used router outside of a functional component or hook.
Convert Post to hook and it should work.

Comment: how ? can you explain ?

Comment: Well the documents will surely explain it better than I ever could. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router The first example is fine. Just put function in a functional component with render and try using it from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this code on application load or on any data change. You should do this inside `useEffect` hook because while rendering application on sever `router` won't be there and `useEffect` runs only inside browser.